# [Prob]Why copy constructor is not getting called

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-elision

I have created a class and initialized an array of objects through constructor, why or why not copy constructor is getting called here? Is it copy elision?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

class ABC
{
    int x, y;
public:
    ABC()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    ABC(int a,int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    ABC(const ABC &obj)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy called";
    }
};

int main()
{
    ABC obj[2] = {ABC(), ABC(5,6)}; //copy elision or copy constructor?
}
```

Comment: Please provide a compiling code... You are missing headers and all of your constructors are private.

Comment: And yes, this is due to copy-elision, try compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors` if you are using clang or g++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's copy elision, the compiler does optimisations and creates objects right in place of memory allocated within array, hence copy constructor doesn't get called.

Comment: Thanks this is copy elision but can you elaborate it more, i have compile the prog with  "-fno-elide-constructors" option then copy constructor is called.